# Can I get a UK Visa at short notice?

Tags: visas, uk

My Husband has won a contest in his office and they are taking him to London from India for 5 days on 7th April 2016. I want to go with him but his office is not doing any arrangement for me, so we are giving money to a renowned travel agency and they are planning a 5 days tour for me on the same day. But we have decided it a bit late. Its already 15th March 2016 today so if I will apply the UK visa tomorrow then can I get the visa before 6th April 2016??

Answer (score 6):

The answer depends on the type of visa you'll be applying for and on where you'll be applying for it.  You can check for yourself at https://www.gov.uk/visa-processing-times.  You enter the location and visa type, and you get back a table showing the percentage of applications decided in a certain number of days.  For example, for a general visitor visa in New Delhi, today's result is:

```
Most applications are processed within 5 days.

Number of days to process application / % of applications decided

2 days    31%
3 days    73%
5 days    97%
10 days   99%
15 days   99%
30 days   99%
60 days   99%
90 days   99%
120 days 100%

Note: actual processing times may vary depending on a range of factors.
```

As noted in a comment by CMaster, if you want to improve your chances of getting the visa before you travel, and if you meet certain conditions, and if you are willing to pay extra, you can apply for expedited processing.  The available services are listed at https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/India/user_pay_services.html.

Comment: What about - https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/India/user_pay_services.html